# Duplicate expressions: better to make a variable or not?

Tags: java, performance, variables

In Java, say I have an expression *X* that occurs multiple times in a function. Generally speaking, is it more efficient to create a variable and set it equal to *X*, or not use a variable at all? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each method?

Ex. Say *X* = 5+9*9-1000. Which function is more efficient, function1 or function2?

```
public void function1() {
    System.out.println(5+9*9-1000);
    System.out.println(5+9*9-1000);
}

public void function2() {
    int variable = 5+9*9-1000;
    System.out.println(variable);
    System.out.println(variable);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to worry about efficiency this early on in the game?

Comment: Premature optimization. Math.sqrt(allEvil);

Comment: Decide based on what makes the code clearer. Often, using a variable helps because you can give the constant expression a name that means something.

Comment: Efficiency is not a significant issue in this case, but repeated strings of magic numbers are...

Answer (score 4):

Neither is more efficient.  Your expression `5+9*9-1000` is a *constant expression*.  The compiler will evaluate it at compile time and only the result shows up at runtime (`-914`).

The [JLS defines *constant expressions* in Section 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).  Basically it consists of literals, operators, and constant variables.

Often it's more convenient, readable, and expressive to have a constant expression rather than multiplying the values yourself.

```
int secondsPerDayCalc = 86400;     // not obvious it's number of seconds in a day
int secondsPerDay = 60 * 60 * 24;  // constant expression; more readable
```

There is no performance penalty, because it's evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable in this case or a function in more complicated cases. Yes, there may be an efficiency gain, but the real issue is the maintainability of the code. Repeated strings of characters like this create a source of potential errors if the expressions need to change.

Answer (score 0):

> Generally speaking, is it more efficient to create a variable and set it equal to X, or not use a variable at all?

Generally speaking, it is **not possible to say**.  It *may* be more efficient.  It *may* make no difference.  It could *conceivably* even be less efficient.  It all depends on what the JIT compiler does with the code, and that is dependent on the JVM you are using, the application, and even the input data.

(In your specific example, the expressions are constant expressions, and they will be evaluated at compile time.  That makes the runtime efficiency issue moot.)

> What are the advantages/disadvantages of each method?

To my mind, the most important issues are:

- Readability.  Splitting an expression into sub-expressions with temporary variables *may* make your code more readable.  (It depends on the code complexity ... and the expected Java reading skills of the people who need to maintain your code.)
- Side-effects.  Some expressions involve side-effects.  In this case, refactoring to use temporary variables *may* change the meaning of the computation.

The best general advice is to leave this kind of optimization to the JIT compiler.  But if performance is an *critical* issue, and you do *really* need to optimize at this level, then you need to do it scientifically.

1. Benchmark your code (properly!) to establish a performance baseline.
2. Profile it to identify hotspots.
3. Modify the code to improve performance at a hotspot.
4. Rerun the benchmark to see if you have improved things.
5. Go to step two ...

(Optimizing based solely on your intuition, you are liable waste a lot of your time optimizing with minimal measurable performance benefits.  Also bear in mind that hand optimizing for one platform does not necessarily improve performance on others ...)